# NetworkManager Scanning not allowed

Tags: python, linux, arm, dbus

I'm using dbus api for NetworkManager 1.4.0  [with python wrapper](https://pythonhosted.org/python-networkmanager/). This code scan wifi networks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import NetworkManager as NM

def ap_sec_to_str2(sec):
    list = []

    if sec & (0x1 | 0x2 | 0x10 | 0x20):
        list.append("WEP")
    if sec & (0x4 | 0x40):
        list.append("WPA")
    if sec & (0x8 | 0x80):
        list.append("WPA2")
    if sec & 0x100:
        list.append("PSK")
    if sec & 0x200:
        list.append("802.1X")

    return list

def MHZ2Chan(mhz):
    return {
        2412: 1,
        2417: 2,
        2422: 3,
        2427: 4,
        2432: 5,
        2437: 6,
        2442: 7,
        2447: 8,
        2452: 9,
        2457: 10,
        2462: 11,
        2467: 12,
        2472: 13,
        2484: 14
    }.get(mhz)

"""WIFI NetwokList"""
def APList(iface):
    check = lambda dev: dev.DeviceType == NM.NM_DEVICE_TYPE_WIFI and dev.Interface == iface
    dev = next( (dev for dev in NM.NetworkManager.GetDevices() if check(dev) ))
    rslt = []
    dev = dev.SpecificDevice()
    dev.RequestScan({}) #this is wrong!!! 
    for ap in dev.GetAllAccessPoints():
        info = {
            'ssid': ap.Ssid,
            'channel': MHZ2Chan(ap.Frequency),
            'level': ap.Strength,
            'security': ap_sec_to_str2(ap.WpaFlags | ap.RsnFlags)
        }
        rslt.append(info)
    return rslt
```

If I often call this function sometimes occurs error

```
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.NotAllowed:Scanningnotallowedimmediatelyfollowingpreviousscan.
```

Whether it's hardware features?

**Platform** ARM CortexA9 Yocto 1.6

**WIFI usb dongle:**

```
ID 20f4:648b TRENDnetTEW-648UBM802.11n150MbpsMicroWirelessNAdapter[RealtekRTL8188CUS]
```

Comment: the error message `Scanningnotallowedimmediatelyfollowingpreviousscan.` OR `Scanning not allowed immediately following previous scan.` indicates to me that you are probably running this code with a very short sleep time between executions. Try increasing the time you `sleep` before restarting the loop. Good luck.

Comment: Error message without spaces. I use sleep with 8 and 20 seconds. With 8 error occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you telling me. Does the timing change if there are many wi-fi spots to test versus 1 or 2 wi-fi spots?  Does the problem go away with using 20 seconds? Is that good enough? Good luck.

Comment: When using timeout problem does not occur in 20 seconds.
I want to understand whether the correct my code. Or you need to call any function before calling dev.GetAllAccessPoints (). I think it is a feature or hardware NetvorkManager, but I'm not sure. Thank you for attention.

Comment: I'm stuipd! I have call dev.RequestScan({}) after dev = dev.SpecificDevice()